# On GCE Kubernetes, how can I create volumes where multiple consumers can write?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, docker-volume, google-compute-engine

[K8S Volume documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#gcepersistentdisk) mentions that only a single consumer can write to GCE PD. What can be used on GCE for volumes where multiple consumers can write simultaneously, for example when hosting a private Docker registry?

I see an [sample for creating NFS volume on GCE](https://github.com/mappedinn/kubernetes-nfs-volume-on-gke). Is there a straightforward solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed [this solution](https://github.com/mappedinn/kubernetes-nfs-volume-on-gke) to

1. create a GCE PD,
2. host a NFS server with GCE volume mounted at "/exports"
3. Use this NFS server as a volume

This was easy to do. One change I made was to add storage-class "" to the GCE PD PV and PVC file as I did not have a default storage class.